# HTML 5, Fluid Pages and Google Mobile Index

Tags: google-search-console, html5, mobile, google-index

I am currently migrating my site to HTML5, at the same time designing pages so that they are "fluid" and are equally presentable for a mobile or a large screen.

I took the fluid approach so as not to have to develop a separate application for mobile devices and I'm pleasantly surprised with the results that look equally as good on an iPhone as they do on a large screen.

Then I went into the Google Webmaster Tools facility and became aware of the Google Mobile Index. I'm confused now as HTML5 doesn't seem to be supported by Google Mobile Indexing.

Does this mean that when I go live with my new "pride and joy" HTML5 site on a mobile it won't appear on any Google searches as it's not in the Google Mobile Index?

Answer (score 2):

Google uses a different bot for mobile content, they recognize a mobile content based on many factors.

So you pages may not be recognized as "mobile content" but still will be in the index even on **mobile devices** (most websites don't have a different content for Desktop and Mobile.. and are fully index on mobile search)

[Responsive pages with the same URL for mobile and desktop are google best choice](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/) of implementing a mobile version of your website.

So you are good.